# Entropy for irreversible adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, adiabatic

For an adiabatic process we know $dQ=0$. So the entropy change should also be zero. Please explain how can we calculate the entropy change.

Comment: Hai @user34124, welcome to PSE. This question seems to be incomplete. Could you provide something more so that we could understand what's your problem.

Comment: A process is isentropic only if the process is reversibly adiabatic

Answer (score 1):

For an adiabatic ***reversible*** process the entropy change is zero.  For an irreversible adiabatic process, it is not.  If you want to calculate the entropy change for an adiabatic irreversible process, you need to devise a reversible process between the same initial and final states as for the irreversible process, and then calculate the entropy change for that.  dq will not be equal to zero for the reversible path.